# HTML iframe and node npm-Iframe doesn't display in IE-11?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs, iframe

I am trying to display, pdf on my web page using iframe or npm-IFrame(Node). It works for all browsers except Internet Explorer (version 11). Is there any update for iframe/npm-Iframe?

npm-Iframe (https://www.npmjs.com/package/iframe) documentation says it doesn't support IE-11.
Does HTML iframe also have any supporting issues?

Here is what I have tried :

1. `<iframe src="./myfolder/myfile.pdf"/>`
2. `<Iframe url="./myfolder/myfile.pdf" allowfullscreen="false"/>` (Imported  Iframe from 'react-iframe')

***Note: I am building my web application using node and React js.***

Comment: I'm confused. Why do you need a JavaScript library to display an iframe?

Comment: IE might simply still need a plugin to display PDF ...

Comment: @ceejayoz : I am building my application using React JS. So, to display a pdf, I can use node IFrame for which I need to import Library. But no import is needed for javascript iframe

Comment: @s.thakur Then you really should tag this with React. There's not much indication of that fact in your question.

Comment: @CBroe : which type of plugin you mentioning about?

Comment: @ceejayoz: thanks for the suggestion. What is the difference in displaying pdf using HTML and reactjs? As React Js also uses HTML tags.